# Proving primality of $p$ when $p$ divides $2^n-1$ with $n$ prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

Can someone prove or disprove the conjecture below? Thanks. Much appreciated.

Show that if $2^n$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod p$ ($n$ prime) with $p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod n$ and $3^{p-1}$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod p$, $p$ $≠$ $±1$ $\pmod {12}$, then $p$ is prime. A more general conjecture to prove:

If

$b^n$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod p$ ($n$ prime) with $p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod n$ and $b-1$ relatively prime to $n$ and $p$.

$a^{p-1}$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod p$ ($a-1$ relatively prime to $n$ and $p$) and ($a$ | $p$) $=$ $-1$ (the Legendre Symbol or that $a$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$)

then $p$ is prime.

My understanding for this conjecture (the specific example with $b$ $=$ $2$ and $a$ $=$ $3$) is that if $n$ is prime, every prime dividing $p$ $2^n-1$, $p$ $=$ $±1$ $\pmod 8$. Likewise in my last post, for base $3$ every prime $p$ dividing $3^n-1$ $=$ $±1$ $\pmod {12}$. When $n$ is prime, it must be the case that all primes dividing $p$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod n$. Therefore concluding that if $3^{p-1}$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod p$, and $p$ is composite, then $3^n$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod p$. By the law of quadratic reciprocity, we also would have all primes dividing $p$ congruent to $±1$ $\pmod {12}$. If $p$ $≠$ $±1$ $\pmod {12}$, then there is some prime dividing $p$ which is not $±1$ $\pmod {12}$. Therefore $3^n$ $≠$ $1$ $\pmod p$ and the multiplicative order of $p$ is not $n$ and is $p-1$ implying $p$ is prime.

Comment: Well $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p\iff a\not\equiv 0\bmod p$...

Answer (score 4):

Counterexample to the title of the question: $n=43$.

Comment: +1. Specifically this is a counterexample because: $431 \cdot 9719 \mid 2^{43} - 1$, and $431 \cdot 9719 \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$, if I understand correctly what the OP is saying.

Comment: @6005: Thanks. I didn't read too deep into the question itself, just referred to the title (which was obviously false).